# CREATE TABLE and INSERT, same query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am having issues creating a table and inserting data to it in the same query. My PHP script is as follows

```
<?php
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($postdata);

try {
    $db = new pdo('mysql:host=' . $request->hostname . ';dbname=' . $request->dbname, $request->username, $request->password);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $q = "CREATE TABLE  admins (
                  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                  username varchar(255) NOT NULL,
                  password varchar(32) NOT NULL,
                  name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
                  email varchar(255) NOT NULL,
                  PRIMARY KEY (id)
                ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

                INSERT INTO admin (id, username, password, name, email) VALUES (1, 'admin', '21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3', 'Your Name', 'you@yourdomain.com');";

    try {
        $db->exec($q);
        output("success");
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        output("Failed to create tables->" . $e->getMessage());
    }
}
catch(PDOException $ex) {
    output('Unable to connect. Make sure your connection info is correct.');
}
?>
```

The table gets created, however, the insert isn't working. It  is complaining that `admins` table does not exist yet. Ok that makes sense. How can I make this work?

I tried modifying the `exec` line to do a separate query to insert, but the `if` is failing

```
$create = $db->exec($q);
if ($create)
{
    $q = "INSERT INTO admin (id, username, password, name, email) VALUES (1, 'admin', '21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3', 'Your Name', 'you@yourdomain.com');";
    $db->exec($q);
    output("success");
}
```

Comment: admin is not admins :)

Comment: Many of us have made way dumber errors :P anyway, fiction's answer below is the more complete tbh. Also, he was the first who answered, as far as I could see :P

Comment: try: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS admins...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You create table named `admins` but try to insert in table `admin`

Also you dont need to insert id field, cause it's `AUTO_INCREMENT` and mysql will do it for you.

Fix your insert like this:

```
INSERT INTO admins (username, password, name, email) VALUES ('admin', '21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3', 'Your Name', 'you@yourdomain.com');
```

Comment: This..this was it. Like I said above in the comments..I am retarded =) I will accept this in a few mins

Comment: All of us sometimes makes errors like this. It's normal, depends on people attentiveness =)

Answer (score 1):

You are specifying value for AUTO_INCREMENT COLUMN. You should leave this value blank so it's automatically populated by MySQL

Comment: Right, I SHOULD know this..I just copied the query from phpMyAdmin output when I manually inserted it and I wasn't thinking.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `PDO::prepare()` instead of `PDO::exec()`